# How to handle a Scenario where two app can respond to the same domain in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-universal-links

As the title states, lets assume there are two apps that are brother and sister apps owned by the same company but branded differently.Consider the following scenarios:

- If I have the brother app installed on my phone and a user presses a URL say in whats app, then using universal links the brother app is opened. No problems occur here and life goes on.
- If I have the sister app installed on my phone, no brother app installed and a user presses a URL say in whats app, then using universal links the sister app is opened. No problems occur here and life goes on.

The problem:

- Now if the brother and sister apps are installed on the same iPhone and a user presses a URL in whats app. Things go wrong and the behaviour isn't defined according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html).

So the question is what now? In 2017 are there any strategies around this? You see on Android when the user presses the link, the Android OS pops up a dialog and asks the user which app they would like to use to open the link and theres no problem. What would be the best coarse of action to be taken on iOS?

Comment: The only resolution I have thus far is to have another 3 that can absorb the universal link and prompt the user if they want the brother or sister app to open. This would effectively mimic the Android OS dialog box. But then I need another app to act as a proxy... really?

Comment: I assume that specializing your deeplinks for each of the apps is out of the question?

Comment: @Losiowaty elaborate more perhaps? Perhaps an example?

Comment: What @Losiowaty means is, you could personalize the links for the apps with the help of the apple-app-site-association file. Then, for example you can use: https://<domain>/app1/<content> and https://<domain>/app2/<content>. Each link would only open in the app you desire.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple documentation you can specify several Apps in apple-app-site-association (AASA) file.

From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

> The value of the details key is an array of dictionaries, one dictionary per app that your website supports. The order of the dictionaries in the array determines the order the system follows when looking for a match, so you can specify an app to handle a particular part of your website.

It is up to you to define order. If brother App has more features it makes sense to put this App first. Common case where such setup is required: developer has Free-lite version of the App and Full-paid version of the App.

Comment: Would this work if the domains were different for the brother and sister apps. I.e the brother app has a domain brother.com and the sister app has a domain of sister.com?

Comment: When each App has separate domain then you have separate AASA file. You can have each App related to several domains via Universal Links. 
For example: brother App -> [mycompany.com, brother.mycompany.com], sister App -> [mycompany.com, sister.mycompany.com]. AASA at mycompany.com will include both Apps.